# How to apply the css pages and javascript pages into /views pages properly in phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

This is my phalcon project folder hierarchy.

```
custom
    /app
        /controllers
            UserController.php
        /models
        /views
            /user
                register.volt

    /public
        /js
            jquery.min.js
        /css
            style.css
```

I have added these `style.css` file and `jquery.min.js` file into `/views/user/register.volt` page, when I view source, those files have been linked as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/custom/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So styles and scripts were not added properly. How can I correct above two links as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The `controller` and `action`  I used is below

```
class UserController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

   public function indexAction() {

   }
   public function registerAction() {
      $this->assets
        ->addCss('css/style.css')

      $this->assets
        ->addJs('js/jquery.min.js')
   }

}
```

The `register.volt` page is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
        {{ assets.outputCss() }}
        {{ assets.outputJs() }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ content() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show full code. Looks like you call `setPrefix()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

check your index.php or services.php or any other place, where your services are. You assets are using prefix. Read more about them in docs: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/assets.html#prefixes

Try searching your project files for this line:

```
->setPrefix('
```